# Mapping plugin taking too long to update model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using KO 3.2 and I am experiencing a weird issue when using the mapper plugin.

I use the following code to get some json data and update my model.

```
self.load = function (item, event) {    

        var d = { expedienteId: self.Id(), id: item.Id() };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Expediente/Evolucion/",
            data: JSON.stringify(d),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json"
        })            
        .success(function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Data, {}, self.Evolucion);                
        })            
    };
```

The data return is:

```
{"Success":true,"Message":null,"Data":{"Id":1,"ExpedienteId":0,"Fecha":"\/Date(1443304800000)\/","Medico"
:"Gabriel R Lopez Gutierrez","ImagenDescriptiva":null,"Sintoma":"Sintomas","Objetivo":"Objetivo","Diagnostico"
:"Diagnostico 1","Analisis":"Analisis","Observaciones":"Oservaciones","CieCode":"Y55.5","CieDescription"
:"Efectos adversos de drogas contra el resfriado común","Tratamiento":"Tratamiento","Pronostico":"Pronostico"
,"Anotaciones":"Anotaciones","RequiereCirugia":true,"Descripcion":null,"TensionArterial":0.00000,"FrecuenciaCardiaca"
:0.00000,"FrecuenciaRespiratoria":0.00000,"Temperatura":0.00000,"HabitusExterior":"habitus exterior"
,"Peso":65.00000,"Talla":2.39000,"IndiceMasaCorporal":0.00000,"PerimetroCefalico":69.90000,"SuperficieCorporal"
:1.99000,"SegmentoSuperior":2.39000,"SegmentoInferior":2.39000,"ExtremidadInferior":1.49000,"PerimetroAbdominal"
:1.99000,"PerimetroBraquial":0.89000,"PerimetroAnterobraquial":0.89000,"PerimetroToracico":5.99000,"PerimetroSural"
:1.79000,"PerimetroCrural":0.00000,"Braza":0.00000,"Brazada":2.39000},"Errors":null}
```

I have 2 problems with this code. 1) The first one is that I need to use **ko.mapping.fromJS** - ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Data, {}, self.Evolucion). For some reason, whenever I use ko.mapping.fromJSON, my model won't get populated. It is worth mentioning that I do use fromJSON in other parts of the application and it works fine.

2) The second problem is: Since fromJSON doesn't work, I am using fromJS which for some reason works even though I passing a json string to it. In any case, although fromJS does work, it takes about 25 seconds to map the data to my model. When processing this line, my browser freezes, i get the Firefox is not responding message and after 25 seconds it comes back and my model is populated correctly.

Any ideas how can I fix this? Either fix it so that I can use fromJSON or if fix it so that fromJS doesn't hang and take so long to do the mapping?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Here is the model for Evolucion (C#):

```
public class Evolucion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ExpedienteId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

        public string Medico { get; set; }

        public string ImagenDescriptiva { get; set; }
        public string Sintoma { get; set; }
        public string Objetivo { get; set; }
        public string Diagnostico { get; set; }
        public string Analisis { get; set; }
        public string Observaciones { get; set; }
        public string CieCode { get; set; }
        public string CieDescription { get; set; }
        public string Tratamiento { get; set; }
        public string Pronostico { get; set; }
        public string Anotaciones { get; set; }
        public bool RequiereCirugia { get; set; }

        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public decimal TensionArterial { get; set; }
        public decimal FrecuenciaCardiaca { get; set; }
        public decimal FrecuenciaRespiratoria { get; set; }
        public decimal Temperatura { get; set; }
        public string HabitusExterior { get; set; }

        public decimal Peso { get; set; }
        public decimal Talla { get; set; }
        public decimal IndiceMasaCorporal { get; set; }
        public decimal PerimetroCefalico { get; set; }
        public decimal SuperficieCorporal { get; set; }
        public decimal SegmentoSuperior { get; set; }
        public decimal SegmentoInferior { get; set; }
        public decimal ExtremidadInferior { get; set; }
        public decimal PerimetroAbdominal { get; set; }
        public decimal PerimetroBraquial { get; set; }
        public decimal PerimetroAnterobraquial { get; set; }
        public decimal PerimetroToracico { get; set; }
        public decimal PerimetroSural { get; set; }
        public decimal PerimetroCrural { get; set; }
        public decimal Braza { get; set; }
        public decimal Brazada { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: add your model code please

Comment: @Everv0id - I added the model. That is what is returned as part of data.Data in  ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Data, {}, self.Evolucion);

Comment: The data you're getting back is JS, not a JSON string. When you tell jQuery you're getting json, it unpacks it for you.

Comment: Same problem in other browsers? Did you debug it also in Chrome? I'd say the problem is not in the mapping, but somewhere else.Have you tried mapping it without binding the model, i mena not calling `applyBindings` and doing the mapping to chek if it runs slowly or not.

Comment: @RoyJ - you were completely right. I thought I was returning a json string but it was indeed an object. After making the suggested change, .fromJSON worked but I was facing the same issue. As per my response, the issue was with the mapping of a property that shouldn't have been mapped to begin with.  Thanks!

Comment: @JotaBe - thanks! It was happening in all browsers but following your suggestion I was able to see that an extra property was being mapped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. It turned out that a very large array properties where being mapped (and shouldn't have) and when refreshing the model with either `.fromJS` or `.fromJSON` it was causing the UI to choke.

After ignoring the properties during the mapping (`'ignore': [Properties]`) the problem when away.

Thanks again for the help!